# SQL Server, include columns that are not in group by statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a permanent problem,
lets assume that I have a following columns:

```
T:A(PK), B, C, D, E
```

Now,

```
select A, MAX(B) from T group BY A
```

No,  I cant do:

```
select A, C, MAX(B) from T group BY A
```

I don't understand why - when in comes to `AVG` or `SUM` I get it. However, `MAX` or `MIN` is getting from exactly one row.

How to deal with it?

Comment: "MAX or MIN is getting from exactly one row." - really? You've *never* encountered a situation where, say, more than one row has the same value in the `B` column and that value happens to represent the min or max?

Comment: What do you want to do with the data in column C? If you want to group it, then just add it to the group part: `from T group BY A, C` Please describe what is the desired output for Column C?

Comment: if your debugger do not allow you to do, it means it is not getting from exactly one row

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` for that like this:

```
select A, C, B
from (
    select *
        , row_number() over (partition by A order by B desc) seq
        --                       group by ^      max(^)
    from yourTable ) t
where seq = 1;
```

Comment: `where seq = 1` - what does it mean ?

Comment: This answer is what I was going to suggest. The sub query t is numbering the rows, ordering by the column you want the max of (B) in descending order, and calling it "seq". You then select where seq = 1 which will be the row with the highest B, along with all its other data (e.g. col C).

Comment: Might be worth mentioning here what happens when there's a tie between multiple rows. In this instance, it will arbitrarily select *one* of the rows.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever In that issue use `DENSE_RANK` ;).

Answer (score 0):

That's cause columns included in the select list should also be part of `group by` clause. You may have column which re part of group by but not present in select list but vice-versa not possible.

You generally, put only those columns in select clause on which you want the grouping to happen.

Answer (score 0):

try this. it can help you find the MAX by just 1 column (f1), and also adding the column you wanted(f3) but not affecting your MAX operation

```
SELECT m.f1,s.f2,m.maxf3 FROM
(SELECT f1,max(f3) maxf3 FROM t1 GROUP BY f1) m
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP(1) f2,f1 FROM t1 WHERE m.f1 = f1) s
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear in that we aren't sure what you are trying to do.

Assuming you don't actually want to do a group by in your main query but want to return the max of B based on column A you can do it like so.

```
select A, C,(Select Max(B) from T as T2 WHERE T.A = T2.A) as MaxB from T
```